# React: what happens when you set the same state twice in a row?

Tags: reactjs

I'm curious what happens when you set the same state twice in a row, seeing how setting state doesn't set the state immediately. For example:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  setState(1)
  setState(2)
}, [])
```

In the next render after useEffect fires, is the state guaranteed to be 2, or is there any chance it's 1? I figure it's likely guaranteed to be 2 as they likely use some sort of queue for it, but I'd like to know for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: It is queued, and since there is no asynchronous behavior or [`useTransition`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usetransition), both of these changes will happen (in order) before the next render (without an intermediate render with the state as `1`)

Answer (score 1):

In React 18 Batching is when React groups multiple state updates into a single re-render for better performance. In React 17 and prior, updates inside React event handlers were batched. But updates inside of promises, setTimeout, native event handlers, or any other event were not batched in React by default.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching